# Vitest mocking $router.push not working in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vitest

I'm encountering an issue while testing a section of code responsible for handling errors during an API call within a Vue.js application. Specifically, I have a method that fetches blog posts, and if an error with status code 401 (Unauthorized) occurs, I intend to redirect the user to a login page. The Unit Test result indicated that the `push` method was called 0 times but it most certainly entered the `catch` block in the component because I did a `console.log` there. I will upvote and accept the answer if is it correct.

The following is my method to fetch blog posts.

```js
async fetchBlogPosts() {
  try {
    const data = await getBlogPosts();
    if (data.posts != null) {
      this.posts = data.posts;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      this.$router.push('/login');
      localStorage.removeItem('blog_access_token');
    }
  }
}
```

The following is my Vitest Unit Test:

```js
const mockTransactionsErrorResponse = (error = {}) => {
  axios.get.mockRejectedValue(error)
}

it.only('handles unauthorized error', async () => {
  const push = vi.fn();
  const $router = { push };

  // Simulating an unauthorized error response
  mockTransactionsErrorResponse({
    response: {
       status: 401,
       data: 'Unauthorized'
    }
  })

  // Setting up the component rendering
  const vuetify = createVuetify();
  render(BlogComponent, {
    global: {
      mocks: { $router },
      plugins: [vuetify]
    },
    mocks: {
      localStorage: {
        getItem: () => 'blog_access_token'
      }
    }
  });

  // Assertions
  expect(push).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/login'); // ISSUE: not called here
  expect(localStorage.removeItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith('blog_access_token');
});
```

### Error Message

AssertionError: expected "spy" to be called with arguments: [ '/login' ]